# Sql DataBinding Against Reading Label/Textbox.text

Tags: c#

I am trying to bind sql data on textboxes against reading data from  label my code is as below:

```
 string sql1 = " select openbal from AccountMast where accname='" + comboBox1.Text + "' and companyID='" + label4.Text + "'";
SqlDataAdapter dap1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sql1, con);
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
dap1.Fill(ds1);
for (int p = 0; p < ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count; p++) 
{
  if (label11.Text == "Dr") 
{
  txtopenbaldr.Text = Convert.ToString(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[p]["openbal"]);

 }
  if (label11.Text == "Cr") 
  {
    txtopenbalcr.Text  = Convert.ToString(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[p]["openbal"]);
  }
}


//Label11 Bind by Sql.

string sql10 = " select obcat from AccountMast where accname='" + comboBox1.Text + "' and companyID='" + label4.Text + "'";
  SqlDataAdapter dap10 = new SqlDataAdapter(sql10, con);
  DataSet ds10 = new DataSet();
  dap10.Fill(ds10);

  for (int p = 0; p < ds10.Tables[0].Rows.Count; p++) 
  {
      label11.Text  = Convert.ToString(ds10.Tables[0].Rows[p]["obcat"]);
  }
```

The label11 bound by sql data and it should display text "Dr" OR "Cr" at a time.

but it's not working as the label11.text not support for bind the data onto textboxes

I have two textboxes as below:

```
Opening Balance/Debit                     Opening Balance/Credit
txtopenbaldr.Text                           txtopenbalcr.Text
```

There are two textboxes which can databind on above condition: Remember only one textbox should be bind as per condition.

I am trying the trick but it's fail. Suggest the solution.

Comment: (1) How exactly is `label11` getting its value set?  As it stands, you're going to always loop through the entire dataset and assign `txtopenbaldr.text` and `txtopenbalcr.text` to the last record.  What are you trying to accomplish here?  (2) By using an ad-hoc query instead of a parameterized query, you're opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks if `label4.Text` can somehow be set by the user.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, Yes I know it's openup for sql injection but it's not my problem i will solve it later but now the above problem have to solve. The label11 is databound by sql table and select the value from the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you simply appended the code for `label11.text` at the end of your message, but that in reality `label11.text` is assigned before you try to set `txtopenbaldr.Text` or `txtopenbalcr.Text`.

If that's the case, I would make sure that `label11.Text` actually has the value `Dr` or `Cr`, and not `DR` or `CR`, as the comparisons will be case-sensitive.

Comment: You are wright it's works now. thanks i thinks it's a big,big mistake from me. i am accepted your answer.